# Pytorch keeps getting out of memory

Tags: pytorch

pytorch keeps outputting the error message below despite me tuning the batch size to be equal to 8. I tried using torch.cuda.empty_cache(), but that didn't solve the issue.
I've also tried proposed solutions here: [How to clear CUDA memory in PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322434/how-to-clear-cuda-memory-in-pytorch) and [pytorch out of GPU memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52621570/pytorch-out-of-gpu-memory), but they didn't work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\MachineLearning\Projects\diffusion_models\practice\ddpm.py", line 110, in <module>
    launch()
  File "D:\Programming\MachineLearning\Projects\diffusion_models\practice\ddpm.py", line 106, in launch
    train(args)
  File "D:\Programming\MachineLearning\Projects\diffusion_models\practice\ddpm.py", line 85, in train
    loss.backward()
  File "D:\Programming\global_venv\lib\site-packages\torch\_tensor.py", line 255, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
  File "D:\Programming\global_venv\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py", line 147, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 1024.00 MiB (GPU 0; 4.00 GiB total capacity; 2.63 GiB already allocated; 0 bytes free; 2.73 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

Comment: Your model may be too complex or your inputs too large for a gpu with only 4gb of memory

Comment: 4GB is quite small for a GPU, reduce batch size to 1 and see if you still get the error

Comment: Okay, thank you, 1 batch works! (what is the point though)